# Javascript click event listener on multiple elements and get target ID

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a javascript file that sets an EventListener of 'click' on every element with the `<article>` tag. I want to get the id of the article clicked when the event fires. For some reason, my code produces nothing!

My javascript:

```
articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
articles.addEventListener('click',redirect(e),false);
function redirect(e){
alert(e.target.id);
}
```

Why isn't this working? BTW my article setup is in a function called when the window is loaded, and i know that works for sure because that function has other stuff that work.

---

**EDIT**

So i fixed my code so it will loop and add the listener to every article element, and now i get an alert box with nothing in it. When trying to output the e.target without the ID, i get the following message for every element:

```
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
```

Any suggestions?

---

**ANOTHER EDIT**

My  current javascript code:

```
function doFirst(){
articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].addEventListener('click',redirect(articles[i]),false);
}
}

function redirect(e){
alert(e.id);
}
window.addEventListener('load',doFirst,false);
```

This is showing my alert boxes when the page finished loading, without considering that i haven't clicked a damn thing :O

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not passing an article object to redirect as a parameter.

Try this (**EDIT**):

```
articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].addEventListener('click',redirect,false);
}
function redirect(ev){
    alert(ev.target.id);
}
```

Hope, it will solve the bug.

Comment: This is showing the id's, but before i even click the item! How can i solve this?

Comment: @arielschon12 : I didn't get it what are you trying to say?Are you saying that it shows alert,even without clicking the element. Its not possible.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. The moment the page is loaded i get alert boxes popping up with element id's.

Comment: Is it happen only during page load.

Comment: @arielschon12 : Have a look at my edit.Hope it will resolve the problem.

Comment: This works fine for attribute 'id' but 'rel' attribute is not working.  alert(this.rel); can anyone help me to get this?

Answer (score 13):

Why is nobody mentioning a single event which checks for the clicked element?

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (target.nodeName === 'article') {
        // do whatever you like ;-)
    }
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

it's more performant to have less events..

if you don't need to check for click events on the whole body you could attach the event to some closer parent element

Comment: Is there any reference available about performance for this solution on previously provided solution

Answer (score 4):

You are executing the redirect function instead of passing the reference, try this:

```
articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
articles.addEventListener('click',redirect,false);
function redirect(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
}
```

**Edit:**
Also, getElementsByTagName returns an array with articles, so you have to loop through them and call addEventListener on each one of them.

```
articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].addEventListener('click',redirect,false);
}
function redirect(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I missed the fact you were using getElementsByTagName. See my edit

Comment: Still isn't working, i get an alert box but without the id. It is simply empty.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a nodelist. You can then add an eventlistener to each one of those elements with a for loop.

```
<div id="test">
hey
</div>
<div id="test2">
yo
</div>

<script>
var nl = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i=0; i<nl.length; i++){
    nl[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        alert(e.target.id);
    },false);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This helped a lot, now i can see an alert box. Problem is, the alert box is empty. it holds no ID when i know my elements have ids. Why is that?

Comment: What does your html look like.

Comment: I just have a bunch of articles scattered around, that is not the important part.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This mini javascript libary (1.3 KB) can do all these things

https://github.com/Norair1997/norjs/

```
nor.event(["#first"], ["touchstart", "click"], [doSomething, doSomething]);
```

This plugin can handle such stuff and more

Answer (score 0):

Sry for bumping this old post, but I would do something like this

```
const myElements = document.querySelectorAll("article")
myElements.forEach(x => x.setAttribute("onclick", "alertFunction(this.id)"))

function alertFunction(theId){
alert(theId)
}
```

That would be if JavaScript is what you need. But today you can use JQuery instead, and that would be less code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
articles.addEventListener('click',redirect,false); // omit redirect(e) inside event listener // and then try with the alert as you did.
```

if does not work then try by e.id instead of e.target.id inside alert as below:

```
   alert(this.id);
```

Thanks.

Comment: when using e.id i get a message that says "undefined"

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?