# Attaching a click event to multiple elements at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code in jQuery:

```
$('.paragraph, .section, .heading').on('input', function (e) {
   localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).text());
});
```

Is there any JavaScript equivalent where I could attach all events at once?

Comment: (element).addEventListener('click',function(){}); in a iteration

Comment: The answer is no, there's no equivalent in plain javascript, you'd have to iterate over the elements and attach event handlers to each element separately

Comment: I would use one listener on a parent element (body if needed) and then check for the clicked element like so
`document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 var target = e.target,
  class = target.className;
 if (class === 'paragraph' || class === 'section' || class === 'heading') {
  localStorage.setItem(target.id, target.innerText);
 }
 e.stopPropagation()
});`
it's more performant to have less events..

this on assumes the elements have only one class each..

maybe there are even more efficient ways checking the right class, e.g. using an array..

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35824451/3484824) with a little more readability

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use **[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** with your multiple element selectors, then add the event listeners to each one

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".a, .b");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to add click event to multiple elements, then set their class name as for example `demo`

```
demos= document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
for (var i = 0; i < demos.length; i++) {
    demos[i].addEventListener('click',redirect,false);
}
function redirect(){
    alert(this.id);
}
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/px7xzsqL/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

Credit goes to:

[Javascript click event listener on multiple elements and get target ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893138/javascript-click-event-listener-on-multiple-elements-and-get-target-id/13894048#13894048)

```js
articles = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
    articles[i].addEventListener('click',redirect,false);
}
function redirect(){
    alert(this);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
```

Comment: he asked for javascript equivalent, you gave him jquery :P

Comment: Pure javascript only...

Comment: Thats still jQuery lol...

Comment: `.on`, `.click` are not javascript.

Comment: @ewrwr you should at least give the original guy credit for the answer lol http://stackoverflow.com/a/13894048/1524085

Comment: Ok @Hemal lets reduce noice on this post. I had an off day on my birthday :(

Comment: @PedroEstrada you nailed it.

Answer (score -4):

[Read Jquery Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```js
$( "div, span, p.myClass" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
```

```css
div, span, p {
    width: 126px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 
<div>div</div>
<p class="myClass">p class="myClass"</p>
<p class="notMyClass">p class="notMyClass"</p>
<span>span</span>
```

Comment: Read the question first, he asked for JavaScript equivalent, not for JQuery.