# How to get DOM Manipulation to work on images?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to get images to resize on click via DOM manipulation. I am trying the following code but it is not working.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")

//these 12 images are stored in var 'images' but do not react when clicked.

images.addEventListener("click", function() {
    height: "500px";
    width: "500px"
});

//JS and HTML files are connected.
```

Comment: [Attaching a click event to multiple elements at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522988/attaching-a-click-event-to-multiple-elements-at-once). [Change image size with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript). You are doing both of these things incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main issues with your code:

1. You're not adding an event listener to an image, you're adding it to a collection of images. This doesn't add it to each individual image in the collection, so you'll have to do this manually.
2. The line `height: "500px";` is a variable assignment, and doesn't change the style of an image. You'll have to set the style directly.

To fix these issues:

1. Iterate over the array and add the event listener to each image:

```
for (let image of images) {
    image.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // Code goes here
    });
}
```

2. Change the style of the image directly

```
image.style.height = "500px";
image.style.width = "500px";
```

The final result will look like this:

```
for (let image of images) {
    image.addEventListener("click", function() {
       image.style.height = "500px";
       image.style.width = "500px";
    });
}
```

Comment: Dang, I should type more quickly :) Frankly, I prefer your answer to mine, so +1

Answer (score 1):

You can't just attach the event handler to a collection via straight `javascript`, in `jquery` you can do something like that (but I'm pretty sure it just iterates the collection via encapsulation). You need to iterate the collection and then add the event listener to each element in the collection:

```
for(let x = 0; x < images.length; x++){
    images[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
       this.style.height = "500px";
       this.style.width = "500px";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two mistakes in your code.

---

**1) You call `addEventListener` on an array.**

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of nodes, and you need to add the event on each manually, like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener(...);
}
```

---

**2) You typed CSS in a Javascript context :)**

The contents of the function must be Javascript code and not CSS.

This should work :

```
images[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   this.style.height = "500px";
   this.style.width = "500px";
});
```

---

The final result would look like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       this.style.height = "500px";
       this.style.width = "500px";
    });
}
```