# use the same javascript for different div

Tags: javascript

I have got something like:

```
<div id="div1"><?php include 'test.php'; ?></div>
<div id="div2"><?php include 'test.php'; ?></div>
```

and `test.php` is:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">test</button>
```

How can I invoke `myFunction` separately for `div1` and `div2`? I mean, if I click on the button in `div1`, `myFunction` is done only in that div. I found `this` javascript keyword, but I can not apply it correctly.

No jQuery please.

Comment: You need to share the code of `myFunction`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13893138/457268

Comment: Is that button literally the only thing inside *test.php* ? If not, we might need to know what's all in there. You may be able to use `this.parentNode.id` or something, but it all depends on the structure inside the two `div`s.

Comment: You should use `addEventListener` instead of inline events. Inline events are harder to maintain and require to expose the functions in the global scope.

Comment: I didnt want to put here whole code, it is a bit more complicated. In `div1` are 6 more nested divisions (divA, divB...) with selection dropdowns. The `divA` is visible. After any option onclick, the `divB` is displayed etc. The same content is in `div id="div2"`. I can use nextElementSibling to display nested divisions one after one. But I dont know how to use keyword "this" or "this.parentNode.id" to determine, if functon is invoked in `div1` or `div2` and nested divisions are diplayed one after one in `div1` or `div2`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter in your function.

```
<div id="div1"><?php $button=1; include 'test.php'; ?></div>
<div id="div2"><?php $button=2; include 'test.php'; ?></div>
```

and your php:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $button;?>)">test</button>
```

So now you can use that parameter to know which button has been pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the context to your function with the call method, like this :

```
<button onclick="myFunction.call(this)">test</button>
```

Then, in your function, you can retrieve the div element by using `this.parentElement`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = this.parentElement.id;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"><button onclick="myFunction.call(this)">test</button></div>
<div id="div2"><button onclick="myFunction.call(this)">test</button></div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```js
function myFunction(ev) {
 console.log(ev.target.parentNode.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)">button 1</button>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)">button 2</button>
</div>
```

You can pass in the `event` object through which you then receive the clicked `target` and and its `parentNode`, i.e. the corresponding `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
<button onclick="myFunction.bind(this)">test</button>
```

Comment: Why do you think `.bind(this)` will solve his problem?